# GParted format help

Tags: gparted

I'm trying to format a USB using GParted according to [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)

Here is GParted installed on my computer:

[image]

1. In the above list, which one is the usb drive? Is it `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda5`?
2. The guide says: **Now right click your USB drive in GParted and select "Unmount"**. But when i try this either for sda2 or sda5, Unmount is unselectable.

What am I missing here? Can someone please tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your USB is not /dev/sda2 or /dev/sda5. DO NOT FORMAT THESE!!!

These are partitions on your HDD. There is a selector in upper right-hand corner, where you can select a disk.

And also it is much safer to format flash drives by right-clicking them in the Launcher and selecting "Format".

Comment: Oops, good thing i asked or i could have done a very silly thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: I still can't find an Unmount option. When i right click on USB drive in gparted there's mount option which is unselectable. And i also dont know what you mean by launcher(I know this sounds super stupid but i installed Ubuntu just yesterday). Is it the section which is on the left when you click Files? If so, when i right click on the USB drive from there, i still can not find a Format option.

Comment: You should see a flash driver icon in the right-hand side panel. Just right-click it and choose format. You do not need gparted for that simple tasks. But you can do it in Gparted. You do not need to unmount, if it is not mounted. Just format it.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. It seems i'll have to ask for every step.:P The instruction says: <I'm not sure if UNetbootin will mark the drive as bootable as my USB drive already had the "boot" flag enabled from Gparted, so you may want to enable it too: right click the USB drive and select "Manage flags".> But when i right click, this option is unselectable. And there are no flags shown for USB,

Answer (score 1):

**GParted**

- Click the entry in the upper right corner `/dev/sda 465.76 GiB`.
- Select your flash drive
- Follow the guide

**Disks** aka **gnome-disk-utility**

- Run `Disk` from the Dash
- Select your flash drive
- Select `Format` from the menu